# HashiCorp Root DB Credential Rotation with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to use this new feature in the 0.10 version of HashiCorp Vault that allows you to rotate the root credentials supplied to the database secret engine. Using SQL Server as my database I can't get this to work.

Doing `vault write -force database/rotate-root/mssql` throws this error:

> Error writing data to database/rotate-root/mssql: Error making API request.
>
> URL: PUT http://0.0.0.0:8200/v1/database/rotate-root/mssql
> Code: 500. Errors:
>
> - 1 error occurred:
> - mssql: Cannot alter the login '%!s(MISSING)', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Doing `vault read database/config/mssql` returns:

```
Key                                   Value
---                                   -----
allowed_roles                         [* imagine]
connection_details                    map[connection_url:sqlserver://{{username}}:{{password}}@sql:1433 username:vaultrolecreator]
plugin_name                           mssql-database-plugin
root_credentials_rotate_statements    []
```

Wonder if you are supposed to supply your own rotate statements. Everything else I want to do works perfectly and these tests are done using the vault root token.

The original plugin info was done using this statement:

```
vault write database/config/mssql \
  plugin_name="mssql-database-plugin" \
  connection_url="sqlserver://{{username}}:{{password}}@sql:1433" \
  allowed_roles="*, imagine" \
  username="vaultrolecreator" \
  password="UnSafePass"`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is a bug in HashiCorp Vault 0.10.2 (and older). A fix is being worked on in a new version:

https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/4745

Answer (score 0):

Your account "**vaultrolecreator**" might not have the perimission to execute `ALTER LOGIN` or `ALTER CREDENTIAL` statements on the DB. According to the [Vault official documentation](https://www.vaultproject.io/api/secret/databases/index.html), these permissions are required in order to execute `rotate-root`

Comment: Thanks. I added all the server roles to the user and still did not work. Maybe I need to add this explicitly. Will try. In the mean time I had upgraded from from 0.10.1 to 0.10.2 just to be sure even if nothing in the release notes mentions this.

Comment: This did not solve my issue. I believe this is an issue with HashiCorp Vault because if I change my users password in SSMS and don't update HashiCorp Vault I continue to get the same error.

Comment: @illug It might be. %!s(MISSING) indicates that the username is not specified when rotating the key. Try opening an issue at [hasicorp/vault](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues), they may help you. I will keep looking for a solution

Comment: I figured as much and yesterday tried exchanging username for name in the write database but it would not allow it. I would guess that there is a mismatch in what the root rotation expects and what you need to write to the database.

Comment: @illug well, now you only have to wait. But I'm glad that has been figured out. I'm leaving this answer anyway, it may help somebody else in the future